# skipping the converting step

Tags: php, mp3, lame

So i have a script in my php file that takes a .wav file and converts it to a .mp3

```
exec( "lame ".SOMELOCATION."/".$file.".wav  ".LOCATION."/{$Sub}/".$file.".mp3 ");
```

I now need to take the file from the url and save it to the location listed above

For example:

it will come in like this

```
 http://someurl.com/audio/something.mp3
```

and i need to take that mp3 and download it and save it in

```
LOCATION."/{$Sub}/".$file.".mp3
```

Comment: My tag is php because its a PHP script. I used to convert to mp3 from wav now i have the mp3, so instead of converting i need to save it as is in the right location. My problem is i dont know how to take the url gived and save the mp3 locally.

Comment: Ah, right you are, I completely missed that. Removing comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the subdirectory from the URL: `http://example.com/?Sub=subdir

```
if (!isset($_GET['Sub']) || is_array($_GET['Sub']) ||
        !preg_match('/[a-z0-9]/i', $_GET['Sub']))
    die("invalid subdirectory");

exec( "lame ".SOMELOCATION."/".$file.".wav  ".
    LOCATION."/{$_GET['Sub']}/".$file.".mp3 ");
```

Comment: I am trying to skip this step. I just want to extract the mp3 from the url and save it locally.
    exec( "lame ".SOMELOCATION."/".$file.".wav  ".
    LOCATION."/{$_GET['Sub']}/".$file.".mp3 ");

Comment: @John Apparently what you want and what you say you want are not the same thing. WHat you mean save locally? You realize this is PHP, "local" is server-side. That isn't what you want?

Comment: ok so basically what i want is this a copy file command  

copy_file_command(TEMP_LOC."/".$AudioFilename.".mp3", LOCATION."/{$Subdirectory}/".$AudioFilename.".mp3");